# EmberJS will not load images when paths are stored as model attributes

Tags: image, ember.js

I have a simple EmberJS app. There are a bunch of images stored in **app/images**. I can load an image from this folder in any template if I hardcode a path: `<img src="images/MYIMAGE.png"/>`.  These images are associated with records though, and I have paths to them stored as attributes of the records. The `path` is a computed property from the `filename` persistent attribute.  When I attempt to load the image through an Emblem template with `img src="{{path}}"`, the image does not load. Ember is trying to fetch the image from this url:

```
http://localhost:9000/images/%3Cscript%20id='metamorph-71-start'%20type='text/x-placeholder'%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20id='metamorph-71-end'%20type='text/x-placeholder'%3E%3C/script%3E
```

If it makes a difference, I scaffolded the app with Yeoman and I have Grunt running a ton of preprocessors on my code (the standard ones that come with the Yeoman Ember generator). I thought maybe the images were being renamed, but the fact that I can retrieve them with a hardcoded path suggests otherwise. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `{{bind-attr}}` for dynamic attributes like that.

```
<img {{bind-attr src=path}}>
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/

Comment: For future readers, bind-attr is deprecated. Just use <img src={{path}}>